# Can one travel from America back into Europe at the moment?

Tags: uk, europe, us-citizens, covid-19

I'm aware that the pandemic is worsening in the US and many countries are restricting American visitors.

I am an American citizen living in the UK for 3 years but looking to go back to visit. I'm trying to figure out what implications that will have on my ability to come back into the UK or Europe from a Coronavirus perspective.

Comment: Apart from health considerations, your previous questions show that you’re currently in the UK illegally https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158089/if-a-us-citizen-didnt-realize-that-they-overstayed-in-the-uk-and-then-found-out, making it reasonably unlikely that you’d be allowed to enter if you tried to return as a visitor, which you clearly are not.

Comment: And this question from the 15th of June: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/157704/95267, so you should edit your question with **illegally** living in the UK.

Comment: I vote to close as necessary information has been left out by the OP which would affect the answer for their specific situation.

Comment: @Midavalo The question is a valid question, and would apply to many Americans living legally in the UK. The OP's circumstances may render it irrelevant to him, but that doesn't invalidate the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as a US citizen you are allowed to travel to the US, as can be found in other current answers on this topic.

As a (presumably) UK resident you are also allowed back into the UK, but have to observe a 14 day period of self isolation. See https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control for details.

For travel to the rest of Europe, you can use the Re-open EU page which shows restrictions for the individual countries - countries not in the EU of course have their own rules. https://reopen.europa.eu/

For most Schengen countries, third country nationals are not yet allowed into the country without restrictions, as having to self quarantine or testing etc, and some countries don't allow third country nationals entry at all.

Comment: As noted in a comment, it is apparent from another question on the site that Joseph P. does not have a residence permit.

Comment: well then it's good I included residence as a prerequisite isn't it? :)

Comment: "Residence" isn't the issue, _permitted residence_ is. Phoog's point is that while the OP is a resident of the UK, the OP is in the UK without a UK resident permit, and thus will not be allowed to re-enter the UK after he leaves.. Your answer refers only to a "presumably UK resident," ignoring the OP's real status, and so is inapplicable (and inaccurate) as to the OP.

Comment: well as long as the question doesn't ask for those specifics, I don't think the answer should be tailored to them. You wouldn't ask for any answer to border control questions to include the addendum: "and if you've been in that country illegally, expect problems" would you? The OP has asked about his illegal residence in other questions and received answers accordingly. We can therefore assume that he knows the implications anyway.

Comment: @JakeDot this question suggests they don't know/understand the implications.